# How do I change the 'Odds Ratio [95% CI]' label in a metafor forest() plot?

Tags: r, header, r-forestplot, metafor

I am creating a forestplot using the metafor package in R.
Whenever I create a custom header, on the right side of the plot the text 'Odds Ratio [95% CI]' shows up. I want to name it differently, but I don't know which argument to use for this.

During my attempts, I have tried three different situations:

- forest() without a header. Then no header and no label on the right side show up.
- forest(header=NULL). Now we don't have a header on the left side, but on the right side we have our unwanted label.
- forest(header="studies"). Now we have our header on the left side, but also the unwanted label on the right side.

How can I solve this? I have added a picture of the top of my forest plot below:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67h71.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Also, please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/forest.rma.html#arguments-1

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Wolfgang in the comments, you can refer to the Forest Plot function description and the header argument:

> **header:** logical to specify whether column headings should be added to the plot (the default is FALSE). Can also be a character vector to
> specify the left and right headings (or only the left one).

https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/forest.default.html

If you provide two character values in a vector to the header argument, you can specify the title on the left, and something else on the right (instead of Odds Ratio).

For example, try:

```
library(metafor)

dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat, slab=paste(author, year, sep=", "))

forest(res, header = c("left", "right"))
```

**Output**

[image: Forest Plot with header including two values for left and right]